# Safari Web Inspector not working with iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, safari, safari-web-inspector

I am using Safari v7.1 and iOS Simulator v7.1 running ios v7.

I have enabled all the options in Mobile Safari in the iOS simulator as well as in Safari browser on Mac (v10.9.5) as per this url: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

However when I run any hybrid app in Simulator or open a webpage in mobile Safari, I dont see the webpage in Safari Web inspector. The Mac Safari option "Develop -> iOS Simulator" shows "No Inspectable application" to debug.

The same **works fine** if I connect an actual iPhone.

Any pointers are welcome!

Comment: This is a goof - all I had to do was restart safari.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

From a WWDC 2014 session 512 "web_inspector_and_modern_javascript", you have to create a `.entitlements` file with these keys. It's about at 22:48 min in the video.

Can't find in [Apple's Safari Web Inspector Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) though. Just weird... :(

[image]